# Kotlin android extension and Custom view in Android studio layout preview

Tags: android, kotlin, custom-view, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a custom view use `kotlin android extension` to find sub view,  everything work well on real device and virtual device. When use custom view in `Android Sutdio Layout preview` throw `java.lang.NullPointerException`

clear and rebuild have done many times

Android studio: 3.2.1

kotlin        : 1.2.50-71

But same code work properly on Android studio 3.1.4

This not a simple NPE problem, this may cause by Android Studio Layout Preview

**Custom View**:

```
    import android.content.Context
    import android.util.AttributeSet
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout
    import com.youzan.retail.stock.R
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.stock_item_setting_icon.view.*


    internal class ItemSettingIcon : RelativeLayout {
        constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
            initLayout(context, attrs)
        }

        constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
            initLayout(context, attrs)
        }

        private fun initLayout(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) {
            if (context == null || attrs == null)
                return

            View.inflate(context, R.layout.stock_item_setting_icon, this)
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ItemSettingIcon)
            item_icon.setImageResource(typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ItemSettingIcon_item_icon, -1)) //NPE here
            item_title.setText(typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ItemSettingIcon_item_title, -1))
            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    }
```

**R.layout.stock_item_setting_icon**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/stock_setting_item_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/stock_setting_item_icon_size"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/stock_content_left_margin" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/stock_10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_icon"
            android:text="@string/stock_query"
            android:textColor="@color/stock_setting_item_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/stock_setting_item_text_size" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_end_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/stock_15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stock_icon_right_arrow" />

    </merge>
```

**R.styleable.ItemSettingIcon**:

```
<declare-styleable name="ItemSettingIcon">
    <attr name="item_icon" format="reference" />
    <attr name="item_title" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.youzan.retail.stock.view.ItemSettingIcon.initLayout(ItemSettingIcon.kt:30)
        at com.youzan.retail.stock.view.ItemSettingIcon.<init>(ItemSettingIcon.kt:17)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor968.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:401)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:184)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:142)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:229)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:421)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:432)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:336)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:327)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:386)
        at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:450)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:590)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there some mistakes do I make ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: not same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.stock_item_setting_icon.view.*
```

This is probably the problem. Kotlin Android plugin only works on Activity and Fragment. You can use `findViewById` with `context`.

Comment: This work with custom view , decompilation code :  `((ImageView)this._$_findCachedViewById(id.item_icon)).setImageResource(typedArray.getResourceId(styleable.ItemSettingIcon_item_icon, -1));`